# How can I get the keys in a multidimensional hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

So with a normal hash you can use this to get the keys:

```
hash.keys
```

How can I get the keys of the 2nd dimension of a multidimensional hash that looks like this:

```
{"<id>"=>{"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test_l", "username"=>"test_user", 
"title"=>"Sales Manager", "office"=>"test", "email"=>"test@test.com"}}
```

`<id>` is unique for each item.

So the keys I want from above are: `first_name, last_name, username, title, office and email`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a hash which has one unknown key with one value : a hash.

```
h = {"<id>"=>{"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test_l", "username"=>"test_user", 
"title"=>"Sales Manager", "office"=>"test", "email"=>"test@test.com"}}

p h[h.keys.first].keys
#=> ["first_name", "last_name", "username", "title", "office", "email"]
```

(But every time I see a construct like this I wonder why it isn't a Struct).

Answer (score 4):

You would do something like:

```
hash["<id>"].keys
```

Comment: `hash["<id>"].keys` is more correct. The OP shows the keys as being literal strings.

Answer (score 3):

The following would get you all the keys used in the second level hashes.  I've used `uniq` so that you don't get duplicates.

```
hash.collect { |k, v| v.keys }.flatten.uniq
```

Comment: or `hash.values.collect(&:keys).flatten.uniq`, which avoids the block.

Comment: If you're using `map` or `collect`, it's idiomatic to use `{` and `}` instead of `do` and `end`. This is especially true when chaining methods to the end of the block. Chaining to `end` is especially ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean there will be several unique "id" keys in the base hash that point to nested hashes that each contain the "first_name", "last_name", etc. keys. If that's the case:

```
hash.values.map(&:keys)
```

will return an array of arrays containing the keys of each nested hash.

On the other hand, if you only have one key-value pair (as in your example), you could do

```
hash.values.first.keys
```

which would return a flat array of keys corresponding to those in the lone nested hash.